# Format a hyperlink loaded from a xml in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to format a dynamic hyperlink which is being loaded in from a xml so that it's underlined and blue.

My problem is the textfield has it's own format properties and the hyperlink is then formatted to the same properties as the the surrounding text within the textfield and users won't know it's a hyperlink.

Is it possible to use code to format the  tag within flash?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the [htmlText property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) to set these styles.

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.htmlText = '&lt;a href="www.facebook.com/example"&gt;<FONT COLOR="#0000FF"><u>Click Here</u></FONT>&lt;/a&gt;';
```

Here is a working example: http://wonderfl.net/c/qLEf

Comment: Thats half my question answered i guess. The text field has it's own format and the text i'm loading is from an external xml file. The hyperlink will be within the <a> tag. My question is how do i only format the hyperlink text in the <a> so that it's blue and underline while the other text keeps the textfield's format.

Ex. xml text
<a href"www.facebook.com/example">Click here</a> to visit our Facebook page

I only want the "Click here" to be formatted blue.

Kind regards

Comment: I've updated my answer and the example. All you need to do is wrap the text you wish to see in blue between the <FONT> tag. You will need to escape the other html entities.